# iframe (youtube) ignores overflow hidden in slider

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe

I have made a custom slider that does not much more than push a inline-block list back and fourth with margins + some JS to pause on hover or if videos are played. The main slider-wrapper has overflow: hidden.

But, in Chrome the youtube iframes appear when the slider animates, it seems to be a graphic glitch, just parts of the "image" appear, and flickers as the transition moves.

[image: On both sides part of the current iframe appears, flickering while the transition moves.]

I have tried to set wmode to "transparent" or "opaque" but with no luck.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gaa813ro/12/

`see jsfiddle`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: I made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gaa813ro/12/

Comment: This seem to be related to chrome version 65 or 64, on 63 it was working fine.

Comment: (Don’t forget to pause a playing video when the user moves to a different slide, otherwise they are likely to end up with a two or more video sound mix ...)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. All browsers seem to work fine with the fiddle. Edit: This is with Chrome Canary, v67 though.

Comment: This in on Mac OS, on chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 we get the issue on 3 different computers. Just press the "left arrow" over and over, and you will get some flickering.

Comment: The left arrow can only be pressed once; when you're back at the first video it doesn't do anything else. The right arrow can be pressed over and over.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on a site of mine, although after testing the issue in Chrome 66 (using BrowserStack) the issue seems to be resolved. Chrome 66 is due to be released today (17th April). I'm hoping the latest release fixes the issue.